# jQuery-UI Autocomplete submitting form onclick of item from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, select, bind, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQueryUI `autocomplete()` function and I can't figure out how to have my form submit when an item is selected.

I think the issue is with the `select: event` but I'm new with jQueryUI and can't figure out how to make this work.

Here's my code which works fine otherwise:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(function() {
                    $( "#search_box" ).autocomplete({
                        source: function(request, response) {
                            $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/suggestions'); ?>",
                            data: { term: $("#search_box").val()},
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                        success: function(data){
                            response(data);
                        },
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                                $(event.target).val(ui.item);
                                $('#search_form').submit();
                                return false;
                            }
                        }); 
                    },          
                    minLength: 1 
                    });
                });
            }); 
            </script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are there any console errors? look in firebug.

Comment: also you have never accepted an answer to your questions, so people might be less eager to help you.

Comment: @tim: Your code works if copy-pasted (minus the AJAX): http://jsfiddle.net/uXHCQ/ with one tweak (`ui.item.value` instead of `ui.item`). What do you mean when you say your form doesn't submit?

Comment: nothing related to this query, any other ideas?

Comment: hi Andrew, I mean that i want the form to submit once one of the items is selected, just the standard thing like Google does...

Comment: @tim: Did you look at the example I posted? It looks like it's posting (it just gives a 404 page because its not a real action its posting to). Is there something different about your code?

Comment: hi Andrew, yes, your code works but the issue I'm having is how to sync up the AJAX data with the success:callback/select:event. Is there any way you can make your source: function (data) more complicated to deal with all these nested events? just fyi, if type in "t" my data is returned as the following array ["test14","test15","test17","test18","test19"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew was correct, see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uXHCQ) he mentioned. If you switch the part with "ui.item" to "ui.item.value" the select: function() now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works

Except if you expect to get the value in your *server-side script* in the page called by action...

For now, no way to find why auto-submit of the form after selection by mouse or by keyboard, and the `$(event.target).val(ui.item.value)` line, don't deliver the value in `$_POST` array

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Alice is also right. You just need to add this line in your onclick function:

```
 $('#search_form').submit();
```

where search_form is the id of your form.