# JQuery Autocomplete Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have managed to implement the `jQuery` autocomplete plugin on my website but was wondering if it is possible to make the form auto-submit once the user selects an item from the search. I have the following set-up:

HTML Form:

```
<form class="quick_search" action="../include/search.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="Search...">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#search").autocomplete("../include/search.php", {
        width: 350,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
```

I have also included the `jQuery` and `Autoplugin` scripts. The search.php file contains a list of the search options.

At the moment, the search works correctly and I just need it to submit the form once an item is selected from the list that appears. I tried to use the onClick and onSelect options within the search field but neither of these worked correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated (I don't really understand js)! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out you CAN use select but not on ui.item but on ui.item.value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#search_box").autocomplete({
            source: ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'StackOverflow'],
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                $('#search_form').submit();
                return false;
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
});​
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uXHCQ/

Thanks to @tim peterson for [jQuery-UI Autocomplete submitting form onclick of item from dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619500/jquery-ui-autocomplete-submitting-form-onclick-of-item-from-dropdown-list)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work with my example above. I tried inserting your code below my selectFirst: false line and replaced "// post your form here" with "$("#searchForm").submit();" (I gave the form a name) but this isn't working. Any suggestions? Thanks