# How to Submit Form When Autocomplete Suggestion Is Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery-ui autocomplete function I'm not getting what I need.  I've got autocomplete working, but right now this is now it behaves.

1. User starts typing and is given suggestions
2. User find suggestion needed and presses enter to put suggestion into textbox
3. User presses "enter" to submit form

I would like to combine what happens in #2 and #3 so that the user makes their selection, presses "enter", and the form submits.

I've found a few [posts with similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619500/jquery-ui-autocomplete-submitting-form-onclick-of-item-from-dropdown-list), but I haven't been able to get a solution working for me.  I think this should work...but it doesn't.

HTML

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contacts" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
        <input id="search" name="search" size="30" type="text" />
        <input class="button medium blue1" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "/search_suggestions",
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
                        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                        $('#search').submit();
                        return false;
                    }
        });
      });
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Thank you, everyone, for the speedy replies!

Comment: Does your form have an `id` attribute? The problem is that you're calling `submit` on the form *field* and not the form itself.

Comment: You do not show us HTML..

Comment: Sorry.  Just swapped in HTML instead of ERB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run search on a textbox, not the form!

```
$('#search').closest("form").submit();
```

or add an id to the form and replace

```
$('#searchFormsIdHere').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify form id properly:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contacts" method="get" id="searchform">
  ...
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "/search_suggestions",
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(event, ui) {
                    $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                    $('#searchform').submit();
                    return false;
                }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, this code helped me a lot, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

put id for form as `searchFormsIdHere`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "/search_suggestions",
        autoFocus: true,
         select: function (event, ui) {
     var selectedObj = ui.item;              
      $("#search").val(selectedObj.value);
     $('#searchFormsIdHere').submit();
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace

```
$('#search').submit();
```

with

```
$('#search').parents('form').submit();
```